# Cannot Set Metadata or Client Reference ID on Stripe Checkout Session

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using a combination of Vue JS and Node JS to use Stripe's Checkout feature. I'm trying to pass a user ID from my client to the server so I can store it as `metadata` on my new `customer` object after a successful subscription.

I include this in my Vue app:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

Then on the click of a button, I do this:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_...')
      
try{
  let response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/stripe-checkout', { user: 'userId2' }) 
   
  stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: response.data.id })

}catch(error){
  console.log(error)
}
```

The `localhost:3000` server is my Node JS app and it successfully retrieves `user`, starts a session, and sends back the `session.id` like this:

```
app.post('/stripe-checkout', async function(req, res){
  let session = await require('./payment').createCheckoutSession(
    { 
      client_reference_id: req.body.user,
      metadata: { user: req.body.user }
    }
  )
  console.log(session) //<-- Checking the session returned here
  res.send({ 
    id: session.id
  })
})
```

But `createCheckoutSession` accepts neither the `client_reference_id` or the `metadata` because when I get the `session` object back, neither one is set:

```
{
  object: 'checkout.session',
  client_reference_id: null,
  metadata: {},
  //...
}
```

[The docs say metadata is supported](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata) on `createCheckoutSession` but I can't get it to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's in your `'./payment'` file? We'd need to see the actual code you're using to create a Checkout Session.

Comment: Your question prompted me to check a couple things in my `session` creation and I found a bug in my code. Looks like it works after all. Thank you! 